# jQuery Ajax, weird response from .NET server

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax, response, ajaxpro

I'm trying to replace an ajaxpro script with jQuery, but the response i'm getting from the server when using either ajaxpro or jquery is something i don't recognise.

This is the jquery call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "/ajaxpro/CMS.ItemRetrieve.ashx",
    data: jsonData,
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-AjaxPro-Method", "ItemRetrieve");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
    },
    success: function(responseText) {
        console.log(responseText);
    }
})
```

And this is the weird response:

```
[0,"\r\n\r\n<div id=\"content\">test</div>\r\n "];/*
```

I'm expecting HTML or XML in return, but this seem to be an array?
I don't understand the escaping and wierd end. I tried setting dataType to json, but it's not json, not html, maybe javascript? Server response content-type seem to be set to text.

So my question is, how do i use this response as HTML, or convert it to HTML?

Answer (score 1):

Without specifying `dataType`, jQuery makes a best-guess at the format of the data it receives back from an AJAX call. 90% of the time it's right. The other times it needs a little help.

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "/ajaxpro/CMS.ItemRetrieve.ashx",
    data: jsonData,
    dataType: "html", // Explicitly set the return data type
    ...
});
```

[More information here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this was the first thing i tried. And im still getting back the same wierd response and the same content-type in the response header. "Content-Type text/plain; charset=utf-8".